# AngularJS PHP contact cannot read property name

Tags: php, angularjs, email

Basically I have a contact form made with angularJS and PHP. and thats hosted on 000webhost. When I'm sending a mail the mail goes through but it also gives me an error. I think thats the reason it doesnt display MessageSuccess or MessageError messages.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at app.js:119
    at angular.min.js:81
    at angular.min.js:112
    at m.$get.m.$eval (angular.min.js:126)
    at m.$get.m.$digest (angular.min.js:123)
    at m.$get.m.$apply (angular.min.js:127)
    at l (angular.min.js:81)
    at P (angular.min.js:85)
    at XMLHttpRequest.H.onload (angular.min.js:86)
```

the HTML:

```
<div id="websiteApp" class="contactRow" style="display: none;">

    <form ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="FormController" novalidate class="contactForm" name="form" ng-hide="loaded">

      <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="SINU NIMI" ng-model="formData.name" ng-class="{'error' : errorName}">

      <input class="input2" type="email" name="email"  placeholder="SINU E-MAIL" ng-model="formData.email" ng-class="{'error' : errorEmail}">

      <textarea name="message" ng-class="{'error' : errorTextarea}" placeholder="KIRJUTA MEILE" ng-model="formData.message" rows="5"></textarea>
      <input class="saada" type="submit" value="SAADA!" name="submit">
      <div ng-class="{'submissionMessage' : submission}" ng-bind="submissionMessage"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('kaidoweb', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']).
    config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

      $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'pages/index.html',
         activetab: 'index',
         controller: HomeCtrl 
       }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]).run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$browser', '$timeout', "$route", function ($scope, $http, $browser, $timeout, $route) {

        $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (scope, next, current) {
          $scope.part = $route.current.activetab;
        });

  }]);

/*app.config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
    $location.hashPrefix('!');
}]);*/

//Contact form 
  app.controller('FormController',function($scope, $http) {
  // creating a blank object to hold our form information.
  //$scope will allow this to pass between controller and view
  $scope.formData = {};
  // submission message doesn't show when page loads
  $scope.submission = false;
  // Updated code thanks to Yotam
  var param = function(data) {
        var returnString = '';
        for (d in data){
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(d))
               returnString += d + '=' + data[d] + '&';
        }
        // Remove last ampersand and return
        return returnString.slice( 0, returnString.length - 1 );
  };
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'process.php',
    data : param($scope.formData), // pass in data as strings
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
  })
    .success(function(data) {
      if (!data.success) {
       // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
       $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
       $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
       $scope.errorTextarea = data.errors.message;
       $scope.submissionMessage = data.messageError;
       $scope.submission = true; //shows the error message
      } else {
      // if successful, bind success message to message
       $scope.submissionMessage = data.messageSuccess;
       $scope.formData = {}; // form fields are emptied with this line
       $scope.submission = true; //shows the success message
      }
     });
   };
});
```

and the PHP

```
<?php
$errors = array(); // array to hold validation errors
$data = array(); // array to pass back data
// validate the variables ======================================================
if (empty($_POST['name']))
$errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
if (empty($_POST['email']))
$errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
if (empty($_POST['message']))
$errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';
// return a response ===========================================================
// response if there are errors
if ( ! empty($errors)) {
  // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['errors'] = $errors;
  $data['messageError'] = 'Vaata üle punased alad!';
} else {
  // if there are no errors, return a message
  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['messageSuccess'] = 'Tänan, et kirjutasid. Võtan ühendust nii pea kui saan.';
  // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
  $email_to = "email.to@khk.ee";
  $email_subject = "KaidoWeb kiri";
  $name = $_POST['name']; // required
  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
  $message = $_POST['message']; // required
  $email_message = "Form details below.nn";
  $email_message .= "Name: ".$name."n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".$email_from."n";
  $email_message .= "Message: ".$message."n";
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."rn".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."rn" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

Also another thing is I also host this site on GoDaddy when trying to send a mail there it says: POST http://www.kaidoweb.com/process.php 403 (Forbidden).

I would be immensely grateful if someone could give me some sort of solution here and if you need to see something more just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your PHP is setting the errors object it is returning to your Angular App:

```
if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
if (empty($_POST['message']))
    $errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';
```

As you can see, in each case it is setting a *different key* inside of the errors array.  In your Angular code you don't account for this, you just assume that all of the keys will be set:

```
$scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
$scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
$scope.errorTextarea = data.errors.message;
```

You can fix this either in your PHP or in your Angular App.  In PHP, you could use an integer array rather than an associative array:

```
if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors[] = 'Name is required.';
if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors[] = 'Email is required.';
if (empty($_POST['message']))
    $errors[] = 'Message is required.';
```

Then in Angular just set the scope variable and modify the view with how it's displayed:

```
$scope.errors = data.errors;

<ul><li data-ng-repeat="error in errors">{{ error }}</li></ul>
```

Alternatively, in Angular just check if the keys are set before attempting to access them:

```
if(data.errors.hasOwnProperty('name') {
    $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
}
```

**Update**

I'm talking about this section of your angular code, specifically the case in the success callback where `data.success` is falsey:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({
      method : 'POST',
      // ...
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
            $scope.errors = data.errors;
            $scope.submission = true; //shows the error message
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    });
};
```

Since you're probably binding to e.g. `{{ errorName }}` in your view template, wherever that is, that will also have to be updated with what I have above *if* you switch your `$error` array to return with numerical indices.

Comment: Thanks for help, though I'm not an expert in these matter in any way. So i switched out the "if (empty($_POST['name']))...." code but the "$scope.errors = data.errors;...." code I'm not entirely sure where to place it, or do I need to delete or modify something as well?

Comment: Updated the answer, I hope this helps point you in the right direction.